# OnClickListener for an item on RecyclerView keeps crashing my app

Tags: android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, firebaseui

I have implemented a RecyclerView using FirebaseUI in my App wherein it takes me to a particular activity. I have called this Activity as TicketDetailActivity. The app crashes only if I try to direct the intent to this activity and works well for any other activity. What could be the reason?

I must also add that I copied the 'TicketDetailActivity' from another project. So could it be a problem associated with that?

My Java Code for the Recyclerview:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ticket_list, TicketsActivity.TicketsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ticket_list, TicketsActivity.TicketsViewHolder>(

            Ticket_list.class,
            R.layout.ticket_item_layout,
            TicketsActivity.TicketsViewHolder.class,
            mEventsDatabase


                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(TicketsActivity.TicketsViewHolder viewHolder, final Ticket_list model, int position) {

                        final String event_id = getRef(position).toString();

                        viewHolder.setEventName(model.getName());
                        viewHolder.setEventAddress(model.getAddress());

                        viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                //Toast.makeText(TicketsActivity.this, "Clicked on "+model.getName()+" ID: "+event_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                try{
                                    Intent TicketDetailIntent = new Intent(TicketsActivity.this, TicketDetailActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(TicketDetailIntent);
                                    //finish();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.e("CRASH", "onRecyclerViewCLick: Failed");
                                    Toast.makeText(TicketsActivity.this, "Couldn't go to the window", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                };

                Tickets_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            }
```

TicketDetailActivity:

```
package vision.google.com.unicesscustomer.TicketsPage.BookingWorkFlow;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import vision.google.com.unicesscustomer.R;


public class TicketDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mBlockedTicket, mTicketCount;


    Button book;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        book = (Button) findViewById(R.id.book_btn);

        mTicketCount = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Total Ticket Count");
        mBlockedTicket = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ticket blocks").child("Arjun");


        book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent startIntent = new Intent(TicketDetailActivity.this, TicketInputActivity.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
                finish();

                /*    // -------- UPDATE TICKET COUNT ------- //

                mTicketCount.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                    @Override
                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction( MutableData mutableData) {

                        if(mutableData.getValue()!=null)
                        {
                            mutableData.setValue((Long)mutableData.getValue()-1);
                        }

                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Intent startIntent = new Intent(TicketDetailActivity.this, TicketInputActivity.class);
                        startActivity(startIntent);
                        finish();

                    }
                });

                // ------- UPDATE TO BLOCKED TICKETS ------ //
                mBlockedTicket.setValue("Blocked");*/
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML for TicketDetailActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="vision.google.com.unicesscustomer.TicketsPage.BookingWorkFlow.TicketDetailActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Date and Time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="Location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="About" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/book_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="91dp"
        android:text="Book tickets"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="vision.google.com.unicesscustomer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="FIDL"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".HomePage.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login_and_Register.StartActivity" />

        <receiver android:name=".HomePage.Changing_QR_widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/changing__qr_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage.Pop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".QRPage.QRActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.TicketsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.IndividualTicketActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.TicketSummaryPage">
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.BookingWorkFlow.ConfirmedBookingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.BookingWorkFlow.TicketBlockedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.BookingWorkFlow.TicketDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.BookingWorkFlow.TicketInputActivity" />

        </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: comment startActivityIntent and try to print toast message on click item of recycler view , check it is working or not .

Comment: Yes, the toast works.

Comment: are you sure it is the right package and layout in the second activity?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was in my manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this line in my manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.TicketSummaryPage">
```

should be

```
    <activity android:name=".TicketsPage.TicketSummaryPage"/>
```

It works well now!